# Remove specific data from firebase using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I'm trying to remove specific data from  firebase using angularjs. But my coding removes all data from it. Any Help would be Appreciated.

[image]

For Example i need to delete the second data as highlighted using the remove button in it.

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="budgetCtrl">
    <div class="row list" ng-repeat="kasu in panam">
        <div class="col-6"> {{ kasu.title }} </div>
        <div class="col-6 text-right total">
            {{ kasu.spent | currency:"₹" }}
            <button type="button" ng-click="deleteSpent(panam)">Remove</button>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row" style="background: #1feb6b">
        <div class="col-6"> Total Money spend </div>
        <div class="col-6 text-right"> {{ getTotal() | currency:"₹" }} </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**My JS:**

```
var nombre = angular.module('nombre', ['ngRoute', 'firebase']);

nombre.controller('budgetCtrl', ['$scope', 'money', '$firebaseObject', function($scope, money, $firebaseObject){
    money.then(function(data){
        $scope.cash = data;
    });

    var ref = firebase.database().ref();
    $scope.panam = $firebaseObject(ref);

    $("#nombre").submit(function() { 

        if( (!$("#Spentfor").val()) || (!$("#SpentAmount").val()) ) {
            $(".form-control").css({"border":"3px solid red"});
        }
        else {

            $(this), console.log("Submit to Firebase");
            var Spentfor = $("#Spentfor").val(),
                SpentAmount = $("#SpentAmount").val(),
                total = { title: Spentfor, spent: SpentAmount};

            return ref.push().set(total).then(function() { 
                $("#Spentfor, #SpentAmount").val("");
            });
        }   
    });

    $scope.getTotal = function(){
      var total = 0;
      $scope.panam.forEach(p => {
        total += parseFloat(p.spent);
      });
      return total;
    }

    $scope.deleteSpent = function(info){
        $scope.panam
        .$remove(info)
        .then( function(ref){}, function(error){})
    }   
}]);
```

On Above JS i'm trying to delete specific data in firebase using deleteSpent() function. I know that i'm missing to targeting the specific data in my JS. If somebody helps me to solve and understand its concept would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not specialized in Angular at all but I think that in your `<button type="button" ng-click="deleteSpent(panam)">Remove</button>` you should refer to the `kasu.id` and not to `panam`.

Comment: @Renaud
 i tried that too. still it delete all the data in my firebase